# PHP: Use a $_GET-Param with multiple other Params within a $_GET-Param

Tags: php, get

yeah, I know, the title is kind of confusing, but no better title came to my mind.
Here is my problem:

I want to use a link in my application, which would look like this:
localhost/index?jumpto=some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234&someparam2=4321

The problem is that &someparam2 is meant to hang on the second $_GET-Param.
It would be like this:
localhost/index?jumpto=**some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234&someparam2=4321**

Instead, PHP interprets that &someparam2 hangs on the first $_GET-Param.
localhost/index?**jumpto=some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234**&someparam2=4321

Does anyone know a solution for this?
I already tried 
localhost/index?jumpto='some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234&someparam2=4321'
but of course that didn't work.

I hope you can understand my problem.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to URL encode your string `some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234` so that php will not parse `&` in the query string as a param separator.

use `urlencode("some_folder/somescript.php?someparam1=1234");`

Comment: I thought so, BUT I have the problem, that this link I wrote is used as a fixed link.
Means that I cannot use urlencode in that case :(

Comment: Sorry, my english might not be the best :D
I meant that another system uses this link, so it is not a link which could use urlencode().

Comment: @AK Then the other system is actually broken, because that link is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I will try using urlencode(), even if it is kind of tricky for my case.